# Find $g'(x)$ if $g(x) = xf(x)$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

If we have a function $f(x)$, and $g(x) = xf(x)$, what can I say about $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$? How can I write $g'(x)$ and $g''(x)$ from the information I already have?

I know that $f'(x)= \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}f(x)$. This means that $g'(x)= \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(xf(x))$. More than that, I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **product rule**:

$$
(fg)' \;\; =\;\; f'g + g'f.
$$

Comment: I didn't think about that. Which I should have. Thank you very much!